# Google Sheet - how to check if value is in diffrent column?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 columns A and B in google sheet and I would like to make 3rd column C in which I will have only values that are in column B and are NOT in column A.

Comment: Do you want to do the comparison for each row? Or do you want to output once all values contained in col B but not A?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a countifs of A given value of B
2. Anything that comes back as 0 is good to go into C.
3. Filter or sort your range
4. just copy paste
   value into C.